# Delete line in file matching one string but not matching another - SED, BASH?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sed, sh

I want to remove all lines in a file which contain the word "test" but if that line contains "test@" then I do not want to delete it.

There is probably some funky way of doing this with sed but I am struggling, I tried to write a bash loop using sed but this is probably stupid.

```
filetest=/tmp/filetest
filetest_tmp=/tmp/filetest.tmp<
line_num=0

while read line; do
        line_num=$(($line_num+1))
        if [[ $line == *rootsh* ]] && [[ $line != *root@* ]]
                then
                sed -e "${line_num}"'d' $filetest >> $filetest_tmp
        fi
done < $filetest
cp $syslog_tmp $filetest
```

As you can tell, I'm a newb at this :(

Comment: please don't use "test" in your description when you use "root" in your example. please don't use "test"/"test@" in your description when you then use "testsh"/"test@" in your example. please be more careful when writing up questions. please?

Answer (score 11):

```
sed -e '/test/{/test@/!d;}'
```

The first pattern matches the lines containing 'test'; the second pattern deletes lines unless they match 'test@'.

Tested on the data file:

```
aaaa
bbbtestbbb
ccctest@ccc
test!
dddd
```

Output:

```
aaaa
ccctest@ccc
dddd
```

That seems to meet your requirements.

> Do you mind explaining how that regular expression is constructed and used by `sed`?

There are two regular expressions in that line of `sed` script:

1. `/test/` — looks for lines containing `test`.
2. `/test@/` — looks for lines containing `test@`.

The `/test/{…}` notation means "when the line matches `test`, do that actions in `…`.

The `/test@/!d` means "when the line does not match `test@`, delete it".

The semicolon is needed with `sed` on macOS (and probably other BSD-based versions of Unix); it could be omitted with GNU `sed`, but since it works with both (and I test on macOS most often), it seems sensible to keep it.  It marks the end of the `!d` command.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how that regular expression is constructed and used by sed?

Answer (score 4):

Use `grep`:

```
grep -v 'test[^@]' infile
```

Usually `grep` prints matching lines but `-v` tells it to print non-matching lines.

The regular expression matches any occurance of "test" that is followed by anything but a '@'. This is fine if you don't have to expect "test" coming up at the end of a line. If that is the case, use

```
grep -E -v 'test([^@]|$)'
```

I don't think it is worth going into why your solution does not work, because it is broken in so many ways.

Answer (score 2):

If you flip your question around a bit, it becomes:

How do I filter out all lines from a file that either contains the string 'test@' or does not contain the string 'test'.

This can for example be done in awk like this:

```
awk '!/foo/ || /foo@/' testfile
```

[Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6530896/delete-line-in-file-matching-one-string-but-not-matching-another-sed-bash/6531012#6531012) also works, I just wanted to give you an alternate version.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a tmp file if you use `ed`!

```
# cf. http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed
cat <<-'EOF' | ed -s file
H
,g/test$/d
,g/test[^@]/d
wq
EOF
```